# Trouble Mapping Recursive Relationship - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wanted to use the classical mappings (Data Mapper Pattern) in SQLAlchemy to take an existing data model and map it to an existing database. I've read the documentation pertaining to what I'm trying to do and feel lost, though I haven't had the time to read it as deeply as I want. My code is throwing the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship Person.neighbors - there
>   are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing
>   columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or
>   specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

I realize the issue is from having two foreign keys pointing to the the same field and SA doesn't know how to choice. I've tried to follow the advice the warning message offers, as well as emulating different ways to map based on examples in the documentation and nothing I try works. I'm dealing with a recursive relationship (i.e. in an ER diagram this would be a many-to-many relationship that relates to a single entity, not two).

Below is some example code. The Person/Neighbor relationship is kind of weird and isn't my actual code but it's similar in structure and represents the issue I'm having.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relation
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from unittest import TestCase


# Domain Model:
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, neighbors=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = neighbors


class Neighbor():
    def __init__(self, person, distance):
        self.person = person
        self.distance = distance


# Database Schema / ORM objects:
metadata = MetaData()

person = Table(
    'person', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), primary_key=True))

neighbor = Table(
    'neighbor', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('neighbor', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('distance', Integer))


# Data Mappings
def datamap():
    properties = {'neighbors': relation(Neighbor, backref=person)}
    mapper(Person, person, properties=properties)

    properties = {'person': relation(Neighbor, backref=neighbor)}
    mapper(Neighbor, person, properties=properties)


# Unit Test (just to see if we don't throw errors in this case)
class TestMaps(TestCase):
    def test_map(self):
        # Setup
        session = self.get_session()

        # Exercise
        datamap()
        model = self.build_model()
        session.add(model)
        session.flush()

    def build_model(self):
        bill = Person('Bill')
        jack = Person('Jack')
        person.neighbors = [Neighbor(jack, 10)]
        return bill

    def get_session(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
        metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[person, neighbor])
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        return Session()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There just just so many issues with your code, that here I provide the full working copy with comments directly in the code:

```
# Domain Model:
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, neighbors=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = neighbors


class Neighbor(object):
    def __init__(self, r_neigbor, distance):
        # @NOTE: the first argument is not "person" field, but a real
        # object of the relationship. I gave it name "r_neigbor", but it can
        # be anything, but not a nammed of the mapped attribute ("person")
        self.r_neigbor = r_neigbor
        self.distance = distance


# Database Schema / ORM objects:
metadata = MetaData()

person = Table(
    'person', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), primary_key=True),
)

neighbor = Table(
    'neighbor', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('neighbor', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('distance', Integer),
)


# Data Mappings
def datamap():
    # @NOTE: here it is easier and less confusing to define both relationshis
    # from one side. Again, make sure that the names of the relationships do not
    # override names of existing mapped attributes.
    # @NOTE: `foreign_keys` is the piece which solves the actual error message
    # you get
    properties = {'neighbors':
                  relationship(Neighbor, backref="r_person",
                               foreign_keys=neighbor.c.name,),
                  'neighbors_of':
                  relationship(Neighbor, backref="r_neigbor",
                               foreign_keys=neighbor.c.neighbor,)
                  }
    mapper(Person, person, properties=properties)
    mapper(Neighbor, neighbor)


# Unit Test (just to see if we don't throw errors in this case)
class TestMaps(TestCase):
    def test_map(self):
        # Setup
        session = self.get_session()

        # Exercise
        datamap()
        model = self.build_model()
        session.add(model)
        session.flush()

    def build_model(self):
        bill = Person('Bill')
        jack = Person('Jack')
        # @NOTE: fix: `bill.neighbors` instead of `person.neigbors`
        bill.neighbors = [Neighbor(jack, 10)]
        return bill

    def get_session(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
        metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[person, neighbor])
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        return Session()
```

Comment: Sorry about all the issues. Some of these are just typos when making the example (mistakes like person.neighbors instead of bill.neighbors). I knew the mappings were wrong and not representative of all the ways I tried to configure. Thanks (+1) for dealing with these and still figuring out what I meant. I really do not want to change the names within my domain model in order to keep my domain isolated from any schema and mapping. I want to use self.person and not self.r_neighbor. Looks like changing to `db_person = Table(...` works. But where is `r_person` defined? used: `backref="r_person"`.

Comment: `r_person` is not used in this example because your test code works only from one side of the relationship. And, of course, you can keep any naming you want as long as the `neighbor` relationship does not *override* (hide) `neighbor` property.

Comment: I have more questions, one I can fit here: I noticed this one the documentation lists a possible alternate way: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship. I tried that apporach but it doesn't seem to work, any idea why?: `properties = {
        'neighbors':
        relationship(Person,
                     secondary=db_neighbor,
                     primaryjoin=db_person.c.name == db_neighbor.c.name,
                     secondaryjoin=db_person.c.name == db_neighbor.c.neighbor,
                     backref="neighbors_of")
    }`

Comment: @Matt: I added another answer due to the fact that it needs some space. The question you asked is answered and it works. But you do not have the `distance` in this case, and technically the relationship probably should by symmetrical (if A is a neighbour of B, then B is neighbour of A).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just another way of configuring the mapping as asked in the comment to the accepted answer:

```
# Domain Model:
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# Database Schema / ORM objects:
metadata = MetaData()

person = Table(
    'person', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), primary_key=True),
)

neighbor = Table(
    'neighbor', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('neighbor', String(20), ForeignKey(person.c.name), primary_key=True),
    Column('distance', Integer),
)


# Data Mappings
def datamap():
    properties = {
        'neighbors': relationship(
            Person, backref="neighbor_of", secondary=neighbor,
            primaryjoin=person.c.name == neighbor.c.name,
            secondaryjoin=person.c.name == neighbor.c.neighbor,
        ),
    }
    mapper(Person, person, properties=properties)


class TestMaps(TestCase):
    def test_map(self):
        # Setup
        session = self.get_session()

        # Exercise
        datamap()
        model = self.build_model()
        session.add(model)
        session.flush()
        # Anna moved in
        model.neighbors.append(Person('Anna'))
        session.commit()

    def build_model(self):
        bill = Person('Bill')
        jack = Person('Jack')
        bill.neighbors.append(jack)
        assert bill in jack.neighbor_of
        return bill

    def get_session(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
        metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[person, neighbor])
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        return Session()
```